# Steer Extender or Carbon Road Fork

Tags: road-bike, steerer

I am having neck pains a hour or so into riding, have been told I should try raising the bar height.

I have tried adjustable riser stems but cannot get on with them. The only other option is a Steer extender, but I have only seen Aluminium ones, and have read attaching this to a Carbon Fork would be dangerous.

Does anyone really know if this the case?

Or would anyone know of Steer extender in Carbon?

Comment: Is this a road bike or an MTB? And how long have you been riding for more than an hour?

Comment: It's a carbon road bike, ride upto 3 hours

Comment: While you misunderstood the *how long* part, clearly you've been riding these distances a while. So how long has it been happening with this bike?

Comment: Sorry about 10 months now, having frequent breaks to keep pain at bay.

Comment: So did it start after a change to the bike, the distance you ride, what?

Comment: There's been no changes to the bike, been that way since I bought it, couldn't return or exchange the bike.

Comment: For us to help you, we need complete information. Please explain in full sentences. Start at the start. How many years have you been riding? How long have you had this bike? What distances do you ride, and has this changed? What positions do you use? Did the pain start with this bike? Have you had a professional bike fitting? What terrain do you ride in? Do you have a new helmet? I'm asking these, because often we try to fix the wrong problem. I'm trying to make that those of who try to help are actually working on the right problem.

Comment: Been riding 6 years started with a Hybrid 2 years then when into MTB with a full suss about 3 years, as my buddies dropped I went into road, this being my first road bike bought last last May, began riding around October, ride anything between 20-30 miles once a week (2-2.5 hrs)  last 2 months have increased that to 35-40 miles 3-3.5 hours.

Comment: Pressed enter in error, Pain starts around the hour mark behind neck and traps and gradually increases, only realised the severity since I increased mileage.

Comment: Don't it again! Yes have had a bike fit where they advised I have a longer stem to 120 currently 100 the longer stem only moved the pain down and made it worse I then reverted back to the original 100mm stem.

Comment: I ride mainly flat road some moderate hills nothing serious.

Comment: Never had pains with previous bikes, started with this. Did some MTB this summer 2 rides and that was pain free. Sorry post has come in bits.

Comment: Any steerer extender is dangerous on a carbon steerer because it ads to much leverage. But some carbon forks do have aluminium steerers.With those an extension would be fine. Another way to alleviate the pain is to alternate frequently between riding on the top of the bar to riding on the hoods. Neck pain is often caused by over tense muscles in shoulders and upper back. Have yourself videoed by a friend and check your position on the bike.

Comment: Will be adjusting riding position se. If that makes a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You said in a comment that you switched from a 100mm stem to 120mm, this made it worse so you went back.  I suggest you try an 80mm stem, maybe it will be even better.

As for raising the bars, you do have some options:

1. Get a high-rise stem.  There are plenty available, look for 25 degrees or even more.  Like this: http://salsacycles.com/culture/new_promoto_25_degree_stems
2. Try a riser road bar, like this: http://www.fullspeedahead.com/products/handlebars-road/k-wing-compact-handlebar/
3. Lower your seat.  This raises the bars' relative position, which may help.  Don't lower the seat *too* much though.
4. Buy a new fork.  Either get a longer steer tube which you can put more spacers on, or get a carbon-legs, aluminum-crown model which you can use a steerer extension tube in.

Comment: I'd also suggest getting a professional bike fit to the list above, explaining that you're experiencing neck pain with your current setup. Best of luck.